# Fixed menu and window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are building a function to fixed a submenu and i have to change the top value depending on the window size.

Here is the demo, but it is not working as expected.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeosing/X6fqW/)

```
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).width() > 767) {
        jQuery("document").ready(function repositive() {
            jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
            var nav = jQuery('.sub-menu');

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 142) {
                    nav.addClass("f-nav");
                    jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').show();
                } else {
                    nav.removeClass("f-nav");
                    jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
        var nav = jQuery('.sub-menu');

        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 91) {
                nav.addClass("f-nav");
                jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').show();
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("f-nav");
                jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
            }
        });

    }
});

jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    repositive();
});
```

May i know the reason for not working and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we solve this, here is the demo:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeosing/X6fqW/3/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).width() > 767) {
        jQuery("document").ready(function repositive() {
            jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
            var nav = jQuery('.sub-menu');

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 142) {
                    nav.addClass("f-nav");
                    jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').show();
                } else {
                    nav.removeClass("f-nav");
                    jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
        var nav = jQuery('.sub-menu');

        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 91) {
                nav.addClass("f-nav");
                jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').show();
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("f-nav");
                jQuery('li.toolbar-destiny').hide();
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Hope this helps other.